# CSS transition takes final state immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I have a problem starting a CSS transition automatically. Commonly this is done by adding a class to the element being animated. I'm creating my elements dynamically by jQuery. When adding the class immediately after creating the element it takes it's final state immediately without transition. It works only when I add a short delay. Not very nice, can this be done in a different way?

```js
function startbullet() {
    var bullet = $('<div class="bullet"></div>');
    $("#wrapper").append(bullet);
    setTimeout(function () { bullet.addClass("animate"); }, 10);
}
setInterval(startbullet, 2000);
```

```css
#wrapper {
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
}
.bullet {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    height:  20px;
    background-color: #0ff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition-duration: 5s;
    transition-timing-function: linear; 
}
.bullet.animate {
    top: 150px;
    left: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
</div> <!-- end wrapper -->
```

Comment: Is this occurring in one browser in particular or all browsers? (e.g. Firefox, IE, chrome, etc.)

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to achieve. Adding a class has nothing to do with animation, maybe you are looking for jQuery animate http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: well it works for me: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqJMpR
no need for keyframe or jquery's animate.

Comment: @Mikey this is about css transition, adding a class with a different position and setting a transition is perfectly valid. animate is overkill.

Comment: @igwan you didn't do anything though, the codepen you added still has the timeout in the js which is what the OP didn't want.

Comment: @igwan I didn't see the transition rules in the CSS. Thanks. Could be that transition is on the next browser tick.

Comment: @hidanielle you are right, didn't quite get the question at start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery.animate just before adding class

```js
function startbullet() {
  var bullet = $('<div class="bullet"></div>');
  $("#wrapper").append(bullet);
  bullet.animate().addClass("animate");
}
setInterval(startbullet, 2000);
```

```css
 #wrapper {
   height: 400px;
   position: relative;
 }
 .bullet {
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   left: 10px;
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   background-color: #0ff;
   border-radius: 10px;
   transition-duration: 5s;
   transition-timing-function: linear;
 }
 .bullet.animate {
   top: 150px;
   left: 400px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
</div>
```

Comment: Fine solution, thanks for this hint! Didn't know yet that animate can be called without parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a keyframe animation instead of a transition, like this:

```
.bullet.animate {
  animation-name: bulletIn;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes bulletIn {
  0%   { top: 10px; left: 10px; }
  100% { top: 150px; left: 400px; }
}
```

Here is a fiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/e3hqghv3/

Comment: Thanks for this hint and the fiddle! Works very fine. Often I have to accept that I don't understand things regarding CSS: Why is this working with animation but not with transition?

Comment: I imagine it's because there isn't really any transition going on, since your creating the element and applying the class almost at the same time. The keyframe animation won't start until the element is on the page. Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you!

Comment: Thnanks for this comment. Marked both answers as accepted. Pity that I cannot upvote.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this blog post](https://timtaubert.de/blog/2012/09/css-transitions-for-dynamically-created-dom-elements/) you can call `window.getComputedStyle` before adding the class to force a redraw, I guess this is done under the hood by jquery's animate function.

```
function startbullet() {
  var bullet = $('<div class="bullet"></div>');
  $("#wrapper").append(bullet);
  window.getComputedStyle(bullet.get(0)).top;
  bullet.addClass("animate");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this additional info!